# Macro that adds new column and applies formula

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to Excel, VBA and Macros... I am trying to create a macro that added column named "XXX" at last i.e. after the last column and then in that newly added column macro should find 2 columns...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.**Copy and paste the Header Format**

> ```
>     .Cells(1, LastCol).Copy
>     .Cells(1, LastCol + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
>     Application.CutCopyMode = False
> ```

2. **Apply Formula to "Response Time" column range**

> ```
> For i = 2 To LastRow
>
> .Cells(i, LastCol + 1).Formula = .Cells(i, col2) - .Cells(i, col1)
>
> Next i
> ```

3. **Convert Decimal Number to Time format**

> `.Cells(i, LastCol + 1).NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"`

**EDIT: [Full Code]**

```
   Option Explicit
     
     Sub addformula()
        Dim LastRow As Long
         Dim LastCol As Long
         Dim iRow As Long
         Dim wsh As Worksheets
         
     Dim col1 As Long, col2 As Long 
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Formula testing")    
    'Find Full Out Gate at Inland or Interim Point (Destination)_actual and Full Out Gate at Inland or Interim Point (Destination)_recvd
    
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Formula testing")
    
    col1 = .Cells.Find(What:="Full Out Gate at Inland or Interim Point (Destination)_actual", _
                After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Column
                
    col2 = .Cells.Find(What:="Full Out Gate at Inland or Interim Point (Destination)_recvd", _
                After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Column
                
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Formula testing")
    
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            
            .Cells(1, LastCol + 1).Value = "Response Time"
            
          ' Copy Header Fromat
            .Cells(1, LastCol).Copy
            .Cells(1, LastCol + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            
          ' Apply Formula to "Response Time" column range
            For i = 2 To LastRow
                .Cells(i, LastCol + 1).Formula = .Cells(i, col2) - .Cells(i, col1)
```

.Cells(i, LastCol + 1).NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"

```
            Next i
    
        
         End With
         
      End With
    
    End With
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Formula Testing").UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: it works but the output is showing in decemal it should subtract that column and give them out as time value... Please see my edits in question part how the desired output should be and what macro has generated...please advise

Comment: EDIT: @jazz , to get Time format, you can use add this code  .Cells(i, LastCol + 1).NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your formula line to below line of code.

```
Range(Cells(2, LastCol + 1).Address & ":" & Cells(LastRow, LastCol + 1).Address).Formula = "=" & Cells(2, col2).Address(0, 0) & "-" & Cells(2, col1).Address(0, 0)
```

Please try the below code.

```
    Option Explicit

Sub addformula()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim wsh As Worksheets
    Dim col1 As Long, col2 As Long
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Formula testing")
      With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Formula testing")
    
            col1 = .Cells.Find(What:="Full Out Gate at Inland or Interim Point (Destination)_actual", _
                After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Column
                
            col2 = .Cells.Find(What:="Full Out Gate at Inland or Interim Point (Destination)_recvd", _
                After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Column
                
        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Formula testing")
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            .Cells(1, LastCol + 1).Value = "Response Time"
            Range(Cells(2, LastCol + 1).Address & ":" & Cells(LastRow, LastCol + 1).Address).Formula = "=" & Cells(2, col2).Address(0, 0) & "-" & Cells(2, col1).Address(0, 0)
        End With
      End With
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Formula Testing").UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```